# Java Game Engine, Similar to XNA

Tags: java, 2d, lwjgl

Can anyone recommend a Java game engine that would be suitable for a 2D platformer run in a browser, with a similar level of abstraction as Microsoft's XNA framework? I'm rubbish at maths and I'm a Java EE programmer by day, so the less low-level OpenGL-stuff the better.

Before this gets flagged as a duplicate, I'd like to point out the most prominent "Java 2D Game Engine" question on SO is several years old, and mostly recommends abandoned projects.

Comment: I started using Slick2D, but moved to libGDX later. libGDX has further cross-platform capabilities, and sees more active development. It's Y axis is inverted compared to XNA though, so porting projects may involve a little maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to try these:

http://joge.sourceforge.net/
http://slick.cokeandcode.com/

Both are based on the [Lightweight Java Game Library (LWJGL)](http://lwjgl.org/).

Regards